# Invalid transport with Sentry for Qt on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt, sentry

What is the correct way to set up transport for Sentry on Android (with Qt)?

I have an app built using Qt C++ with Sentry. Sentry runs fine for the most part, but it outputs `discarding envelope due to invalid transport` instead of sending any events. I followed the how-to for Qt and it didn't mention setting the transport. What is the correct kind to use?

Tried using crashpad, but it says it's unsupported on Android.

In the future, I want to do logging on iOS as well which Sentry Native does not appear to support, so I am not against alternative frameworks if anyone knows of any.

Answer (score 1):

In your Qt `main.cpp` You need to call `SentryAndroid.init(context)` via JNI. This initialises the transport.

ref: [sentry-java issue 3229](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/3229)

Answer (score 0):

The [Sentry Native](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-native) SDK by itself is not compatible with Android. It misses important bits that allow it to capture crashes and other functionalities.

To use Sentry on Android, you need to use the [Sentry SDK for Android](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/), which bundles Sentry Native with the correct modifications needed to work on Android.

In other words, [Sentry Native](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-native) on Android is installed through the [Sentry SDK for Android](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/) which includes the stackwalker and transport needed on Android. On iOS, you can use Sentry Cocoa (crashpad doesn't work there either).

You can get the Qt integration into an Android app by following the suggestion on this issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/1626

Comment: I have Sentry being compiled manually already with Qt Integration. What change specifically are you suggesting?

Comment: Are you adding the Sentry SDK for Android and Not Sentry Native directly?

Comment: I am only adding sentry-native by compiling it with CMake and including the dynamic library in a static library (which is the app).

Comment: That's not going to work as I described in my answer. I'll further clarify